# How to make a comma separated list

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am new to Ubuntu and need some help to create a comma separated list that will be put into terminal. I am trying to set up a logitech 650 remote to be used with xbmc. This is what I need to type into terminal:

```
sudo ir-keyable -p (X)
```

where (X) is a comma separated list of supported protocols which are

```
NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP XMP other
```

Thanks for the help. 
Cheers.

Comment: `echo 1. NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP; echo 2. MP` You want this? (it will output 1. NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP in the first line and 2. MP in another.)

Comment: just tried that and it did not work. Could you explain to me what a comma separated list is and what it looks like. Thanks Star OS

Comment: Don't overthink this: it just means to type commas instead of spaces between the items: `NEC,RC-5,RC-6,JVC,SONY,SANYO,LIRC,RC-5,SZ,SHARP,XMP`

Comment: What steeldriver said, just replace the spaces with a comma. For that matter if the string is very long you can do something like this: `<<<'NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP XMP' tr ' ' ','` (obviously it's not that it'd make too much sense for the string in question, just for the sake of the example).

Comment: Thanks all. Got to remember KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid)

Answer (score 0):

As steeldriver properly pointed out, all you have to do is to put commas after each item in the command, like so:

```
sudo ir-keyable -p NEC,RC-5,RC-6,JVC,SONY,SANYO,LIRC,RC-5,SZ,SHARP,XMP
```

But of course, we as Linux users love our command-line and scripting solutions, so one possible solution that you could use is `tr`:

```
$ echo NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP XMP | tr ' ' ','                                           
NEC,RC-5,RC-6,JVC,SONY,SANYO,LIRC,RC-5,SZ,SHARP,XMP
```

Or maybe you like `awk`:

```
echo NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP XMP | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf $i;if(i<NF)printf ","}}'
```

But surely python can do the job too:

```
python -c 'import sys;stuff=sys.stdin.read();print ",".join(stuff.split())' <<< "NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC RC-5 SZ SHARP XMP"
```